# How to make front-end forms to modify ACF values on listings?

Tags: wordpress, advanced-custom-fields, custom-fields

I bought a theme on ThemeForest to create listings. Users have access to a platform to create listings, edit them and also delete them. Each listing has its own page on the site.

I decided to add two new fields, one for the company's creation date and one for the number of employees in the company. My two fields have the following names `nombre_d’employes`= number of employees and `annee_de_creation` = company's creation date.

I can display the content of my ACF on the referencing pages via the following code
`Création : <?php the_field( 'annee_de_creation' ); ?>` and `Employés : <?php the_field( 'nombre_d’employes' ); ?>`. It's work fine.

But my problem is how can I allow users to change this from their configuration panel. The theme allows you to modify fields like opening hours, etc., and I tried to create my own code, but without success.

Here is all the code for the listing modification page (with the fields, etc.)

```
<div class="tr-single-box">
  <div class="tr-single-header">
    <h4><i class="ti-headphone"></i> <?php echo esc_html__('Business information', 'reveal-listing'); ?>
    </h4>
  </div>
  <div class="tr-single-body">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label><?php echo esc_html__('Email', 'reveal-listing'); ?></label>
          <input class="form-control" value="<?php echo reveal_get_listing_meta($editpostid, 'rlisting_email'); ?>"
            name="rlemail" type="email" placeholder="business@gmail.com">
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label><?php echo esc_html__('Mobile', 'reveal-listing'); ?></label>
          <input class="form-control" value="<?php echo reveal_get_listing_meta($editpostid, 'rlisting_mobile'); ?>"
            name="rlmobile" type="text" placeholder="91 245 254 8745">
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label><?php echo esc_html__('Website', 'reveal-listing'); ?></label>
          <input class="form-control" value="<?php echo reveal_get_listing_meta($editpostid, 'rlisting_website'); ?>"
            name="rlwebsite" type="text" placeholder="https://yoursite.com/">
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label><?php echo esc_html__('Fax No', 'reveal-listing'); ?></label>
          <input class="form-control" value="<?php echo reveal_get_listing_meta($editpostid, 'rlisting_fax_no'); ?>"
            name="rlfax" type="text" placeholder="256 254 7854">
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label><?php echo esc_html__('Address', 'reveal-listing'); ?></label>
          <input class="form-control" value="<?php echo reveal_get_listing_meta($editpostid, 'rlisting_address'); ?>"
            name="rladdress" type="text" placeholder="e.g 34 Wigmore Street, Canada">
        </div>
      </div>
      
          <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label>Employés</label>
          <input class="form-control" name="remploye" type="number" placeholder="12" value="<?php the_field( 'remploye' ); ?>">
        </div>
      </div>
      
      <!-- test last -->
      
            <?php acf_form_head(); ?>
      
      
          <div id="primary">
              <div id="content" role="main">
      
                                                  
                      <p>My custom field: <?php the_field('remploye', get_the_ID();); ?></p>
                      
                      <?php acf_form(); ?>
      
                      
              </div><!-- #content -->
          </div><!-- #primary -->
      
      
            
      <!-- end test -->
      
      
      <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label>Année de création</label>
          <input class="form-control" name="rfondation" type="number" placeholder="2004" value="<?php the_field( 'annee_de_creation' ); ?>">
        </div>
      </div>
      An :<?php the_field( 'annee_de_creation' ); ?>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

And I give you below my code that I added in the page to facilitate the reading. My first attempt was to call the field like this

```
<div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label>Année de création</label>
          <input class="form-control" name="rfondation" type="number" placeholder="2004" value="<?php the_field( 'annee_de_creation' ); ?>">
        </div>
      </div>
      An :<?php the_field( 'annee_de_creation' ); ?>
    </div>
```

It didn't work, so I tried this way, but still without success.

```
<?php acf_form_head(); ?>
      
      
          <div id="primary">
              <div id="content" role="main">
      
                                                  
                      <p>My custom field: <?php the_field('remploye', get_the_ID();); ?></p>
                      
                      <?php acf_form(); ?>
      
                      
              </div><!-- #content -->
          </div><!-- #primary -->
```

Do you have any idea how I should go about making my code work? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the [Create a front end form](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/create-a-front-end-form/) ACF docs, it appears you are calling `acf_form_head()` in the wrong place.

You should call `acf_form_head()` function before calling the wordpress `get_header()` function.

Example below taken from [ACF docs](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/create-a-front-end-form/)...

```php
<?php acf_form_head(); ?>
<?php get_header(); ?>

    <div id="primary">
        <div id="content" role="main">

            <?php /* The loop */ ?>
            <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
                
                <h1><?php the_title(); ?></h1>
                
                <?php the_content(); ?>
                
                <p>My custom field: <?php the_field('my_custom_field'); ?></p>
                
                <?php acf_form(); ?>

            <?php endwhile; ?>

        </div><!-- #content -->
    </div><!-- #primary -->

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```